# How to add a name to this time series data in R

Tags: r, time, series

How to add the names to the variable in this time series data.

```
gnp <- ts(cumsum(1 + round(rnorm(100), 2)),
          start = c(1954, 7), frequency = 12)
plot(gnp) # using 'plot.ts' for time-series plot
```

Comment: names(gnp) <- c(name1,name2,...) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It needs to have 2 dimensions in order that the series have a name.  Change its dimensions to n x 1 and add a column name.  Note that the vertical axis of the plot now refers to the new column name `X`.

```
dim(gnp) <- dim(matrix(gnp))
colnames(gnp) <- "X"
plot(gnp)
```